woocommerce_checkout_fields woocommerce hook doesn't work in custom plugin wordpress, what is the solution?
i'm writing a simple plugin in WordPress; in the root file, i wrote something like this to modify woocommerce checkout page:
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test Plugin
Description: Test Plugin
Version: 1.0.0
*/

 add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout', 10 );
function custom_checkout($fields)
{
  var_dump($fields);
}

woocommerce_checkout_fields hook doesn't trigger at all. i suspect maybe the issue is related to order of loading so i wrote the code on wp_footer action after checkout full load:
<?php

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_load', 20 );
function custom_load() {
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout', 10 );
        function custom_checkout($fields)
        {
            var_dump($fields);
        }
    }
}

it didn't trigger again. also i tried different priority like 9999 and 1, didn't work again.i tried different level of loading. nothing worked!
im using wordpress 6.7 and woocommerce 9.4.1
what is the solution? did you encounter this issue too?
p.s: my question is about not running this specific hook at all on custom plugin level, its not about running but not doing the right thing! so its not duplicated question!

Did you activate the plugin? The first snippet is working on my test installation.

@gael yes i activated plugin, also i could access to woocommerce_default_address_fields but not woocommerce_checkout_fields. so if it triggered on your machine, it could be related to my env somehow?

try a different hook. is_{something} functions only work in the loop. so is_checkout never happens in the footer. in such cases is_{something}(get_the_id()) can be used

did you try using default theme such as storefront and/or disabling any plugin related to woocommerce checkout process?

@gael i disabled all plugin exept woocommerce and my test plugin. yes i used that theme too, i used many different themes including default wordpress theme like twenty twnet four and themes like Astra. nothing happened at all. i also used different version of wordpress and woocommerce to test them and this hook don't work on them at all.

@xmrrabbitx your post is not a duplicate but the question pointed should help you solve your problem. I guess if you installed wp wc recently, HPOS is probably activated on your installation (which is not on mine) and you could try to disable it as proposed in the pointed answer or find the solution compatible with this new method.

@gael thank you, yes i saw that, disabling HOPS is not a good solution and i read the woocommerce docs, it appears they don't want to allow third party developers to change checkout page anymore and adding new feilds to checkout page is not possible.  i think i must create my fields as seperate section from checkout page in case HOPS is active.
